# Npm run generate not generating routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am using vue-router in a nuxt project and when i run npm run generate it generates everything except my pages. I think it has got something to do with the router because before using vue router i had no problems with generating the pages   **Here is my router:**

**router.js**

````
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from "vue-router"
import Home from '../debonkelaer/pages/index.vue'
import actueel from '../debonkelaer/pages/actueel.vue'
import impressies from '../debonkelaer/pages/impressies.vue'
import reglement from '../debonkelaer/pages/reglement.vue'
import reserveren from '../debonkelaer/pages/reserveren.vue'
import tarieven from '../debonkelaer/pages/Tarieven.vue'
import ingelogd from '../debonkelaer/pages/ingelogd.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

Vue.use(Router);

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/actueel',
        name: 'Actueel',
        component: actueel
    },
    {
        path: '/impressies',
        name: 'Impressies',
        component: impressies
    },
    {
        path: '/reserveren',
        name: 'Reserveren',
        component: reserveren
    },
    {
        path: '/tarieven',
        name: 'Tarieven',
        component: tarieven
    },
    {
        path: '/reglement',
        name: 'Reglement',
        component: reglement
    },
    {
        path: '/ingelogd',
        name: 'Ingelogd',
        component: ingelogd,
    }
]

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/',
    routes
})

export function createRouter() {
    return router
};```

If you need any additional code please reply.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working with `nuxt.js` all routes are automatically generating from all your files in your `pages`directory. That means you don't need to manually declare  every route!

Be sure to check out the official documentation for [nuxt.js: Automatic Routing](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/routing#automatic-routes)

To check for auth you should use [`middleware`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware).

If you only need it for one specific route/component, you can use something like the following code in your component's exported function

```
middleware({ redirect }) {
  // If the user is not authenticated
  const authenticated = YOUR_AUTH
  if (!authenticated) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I know that but i need to make one link not accessible if you're not authenticated. idkwhatsgoingon

Comment: @KeaganMulder check the answer now. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much! that works but it is just the same problem with npm run generate but i found the problem i installed a git repo "@nuxtjs/router" which fd my project. So i luckily have a backup and work from there!

Comment: Perfect - happy coding :)